# Adding a NAT to an existing VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk application with an existing VPC. I need the outbound traffic to go through a single IP address. Is there a way to add a NAT to an existing VPC?

Or is there a better way to add an outbound IP address?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a NAT instance for your existing VPC, just add the instance and change the route tables. I'd recommend you add an Elastic IP (EIP) to an Elastic Network Interface (ENI) attached to the NAT instance, so the outbound address is fixed and you can easily change the ENI to another instance, when you need to scale throughput. Note that network throughput is define by the instance type.

**UPDATE:** Consider using NAT Gateways instead of NAT Instances: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/introducing-amazon-vpc-nat-gateway-a-managed-nat-service/

Comment: Thank you!

I'm stuck on how to add the NAT to the VPC outbound traffic. The NAT is in the VPC its just a matter of directing outbound traffic through this NAT. How do you add the NAT to the outbound traffic in the VPC?

Comment: You can create a Route Table with two rows, one directing your VPC range to local and everything else (0.0.0.0/0) to the NAT instance.

Comment: A good way to see it in action is using the VPC wizard and create a new VPC with a NAT instance pre-build and check the routing tables

Comment: Also try taking this free hands on lab: https://qwiklabs.com/focuses/preview/1381?locale=en